# Is there a term for software that allows users who don't understand DBs to create reports from a DB?

Tags: database

Is there a term for software that allows users who don't understand DBs to create reports from a DB?

A customer might just say I wanna see people and addresses that are related to this incident, for example, but maybe they have no concept of joins, so they need some kind of GUI.

Answer (score 5):

The term is : "Reporting tool"

With this term you can do a search on the web, don't forget to add your DB, because reporting doesn't always work with all DBs